# Is it possible to setup Doctrine to use custom schema for storing migration_versions table?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I'm trying to setup environment in which several Symfony REST API projects (microservices actually) live in single Postgres database but occupy different schemas in DB.

There is no problem to use @ORM\Table to define schema but I found out that migration_versions table is still living in public schema. And blindly hitting 'Yes' while applying migration in the second project just removes the table for the first one.

Of course, I could manually trim generated migration class not to allow execute DROP TABLE statement. But is it possible to setup Doctrine to use custom schema for storing migration_versions table thus completely isolating one project from the others within a single database?
I use Symfony 5 and doctrine migrations 3.2

I had this configuration:

```
doctrine_migrations:
#    table_name: 'd_mkgo_planning.migration_versions'
    migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
#    enable_profiler: false
    storage:
        # Default (SQL table) metadata storage configuration
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'doctrine_migration_versions_planning'
            version_column_name: 'version'
            version_column_length: 192
            executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'
```

And this:

```
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            default_connection: default
            connections:
                default:
                    url: 'postgresql://%env(DB_APP_USER)%:%env(DB_APP_PASS)%@%env(DB_HOST)%:%env(DB_PORT)%/%env(DB_NAME)%'
                    driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                    charset: utf8
```

Also i use listener for table schema:

```
class TableSchemaSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    protected $schemaName = '';

    public function __construct($schemaName)
    {
        $this->schemaName = (string) $schemaName;
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        if (!$classMetadata->isInheritanceTypeSingleTable() || $classMetadata->getName() === $classMetadata->rootEntityName) {
            $classMetadata->setPrimaryTable([
                'schema' => $this->schemaName
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array('loadClassMetadata');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `table_name: 'another_schema.doctrine_migration_versions_planning'` work?

Comment: @madflow No i can't found anything